# epoll_wait stores a different value in "epoll_event"

Tags: c, linux, epoll

I'll try keep this simple. I have the code below:

```
epoll_event event;

event.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLET;
event.data.fd = clientSock; // this is equal to "7"
event.data.ptr = myPtr;
epoll_ctl(epoll, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, client, &event);


//Another thread

 epoll_wait(epoll, &event2, MAX_EVENTS, EPOLL_TIMEOUT);

 // This is the strange part... 
 cout << event2.data.fd; //output is different from "7"
```

But, if I dont add a ptr to `event.data.ptr` (which I did before I called `epoll_wait`), the value of `event2.data.fd` is correct (7). What's causing this?

Comment: Is this really C?  It looks more like C++ with the use of `cout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The type of the `data` member of `struct epoll_event` is a *`union`*](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/epoll_ctl.2.html).  As such, only one of its members contains a value at any given time, so when you assign to `event.data.ptr` you replace the value previously written to `event.data.fd`.  The subsequent `epoll_ctl` call therefore probably does not express interest in the events you think it does, but in any case, you should expect to read back only the `ptr` member from the resulting event data, not the `fd` member.